# Although I set only 1 thread, Spark uses all available cores

Tags: apache-spark

I want to run Spark with only 1 thread. But whatever option I tried, Spark always used all 8 cores in my CPU.

I tried various mixtures of `--master local`, `--master local[1]`, `--executor-cores 1`, `--total-executor-cores 1`, `--conf spark.max.cores=1` options but nothing worked. When I see the `top` result on my Ubuntu 14.04, CPU usage is always about 600% (approximately 75% * 8 cores).

My goal is to compare running time of Spark tasks by varying number of cores used. Please help!

** Added

I'm working on the code from https://github.com/amplab/SparkNet/blob/master/src/main/scala/apps/CifarApp.scala . Sincerely thank you for everybody's help.

Comment: Can you share some of the code you're using? Specifically, where you first load an RDD? If you're using `SparkContext.parallelize`, notice that it can take a second Int argument (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#parallelize(scala.collection.Seq, int, scala.reflect.ClassTag)) indicating the number of parts; If you set it to 1, you might achieve what you're trying to achieve - RDD will only have one part so only one core will be able to process it (unless data is repartitioned further down, of course).

Comment: @TzachZohar Thank you for your help. I edited my post and added the link of the source code. I've been working on this problem for several days and still I don't know the answer...

Comment: SparkNet [README](https://github.com/amplab/SparkNet/blob/master/README.md#quick-start) suggests that the last argument for this command is the number of workers to use (5 in the README example) - what value are you passing for this argument?

Comment: @TzachZohar I tried various values such as 1, 2, 5, 8 and so on. Even when I used 1 for the last argument, CPU usage from `top` is still around 600%.

Comment: @TzachZohar Oh, I turned the GPU option off by changing the `Net.scala` file which is also in the SparkNet project. If I turn the GPU option on, then the reverse situation happens. No matter how many threads I set on the option, only 130% of the CPU is used.

Comment: Just for the record  conf option is `spark.cores.max` not `spark.max.cores`. Not that it matters here.

Comment: Maybe if you try `spark.executor.cores` set to 1 in your config file (/conf/spark-defaults.conf) before starting the Worker  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're mixing options which belong to different deployment modes. Parameters like `spark.cores.max` (not `spark.max.cores`) or `spark.executor.cores` are meaningful only in a Standalone Mode (not the same as local) and on Yarn.

In case of a local mode the only thing that really matters is the parameter *n* passed with master definition (`local[n]`). It doesn't mean that `local[1]` will run only using one thread. Spark alone is using a number of different threads (20 or so if I remember correctly) for bookkeeping, supervising, shuffles, UI and other stuff.

What is limited is the number of the executor threads. It still doesn't mean that a single executor cannot start more than one thread which is most likely the case here. You're using libraries which are designed for parallel execution. If you don't use GPU then computations are most likely executed in parallel on the CPUs. All of that is independent and not controlled by Spark itself. If you want a full control you should execute your application in a restricted environment like VM or container.

Answer (score -2):

The code you referred to uses `SparkContext.parallelize(...)` without setting the `numPartitions` argument. This means that the value of `spark.default.parallelism` (see [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior)) is used to decide the number of parts == cores to use.

From the docs, this parameter defaults to:

> For operations like parallelize with no parent RDDs, it depends on the cluster manager:
>
> - Local mode: number of cores on the local machine

So, adding `--conf spark.default.parallelism=1` to your command should make these RDDs use a single partition, thus use a single core.

Comment: I ran this command: `spark-submit --master local --class apps.CifarApp --conf spark.default.parallelism=1 ./target/scala-2.10/sparknet-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 1` but still the CPU usage is 600%. One interesting thing is that CPU usage of CPU0~CPU6 are 70% while the usage of CPU7 is 98%.

Comment: On the other hand, for example if `spark.default.parallelism` is set to `5`, then even if I set `--master local` (which will allow Spark to use only 1 thread) will Spark run 5 parallel threads? Thank you for your help, @TzachZohar !!

Comment: App does not interpret other params because it need not spark internally uses all params pass through command line while creating SparkContext.